# AWS CORS HTTP API Preflight request not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest

The AWS HTTP API is configured as shown below.

[AWS API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f81XI.png)

The CORS Preflight request is still throwing the following error:

[Preflight response from the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNRyM.png)

CORS headers is missing in the pre flight. I have tried to configure it in different without luck.

And I do not have the options configured in the routes of the HTTP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it by removing the CORS configuration and adding a route OPTIONS with a lambda integration to return the relevant CORS headers.

Unlike the REST API aws API gateway the OPTIONS do not seems to have a mock integration.

Comment: Hi, I am running in to the same problem. Could you please share how you implemented the lambda function for the OPTIONS route? This is my current lambda function but I can't get it to send the headers back. `{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "0"
  }
}`